# PyQt 5.6: connecting to a DBus signal hangs

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, dbus

I'm trying to connect a slot to a signal emitted through DBus in PyQt 5.6 with Python 3.5.

When I run my script like this `QDBUS_DEBUG=1 python3 qtdbustest.py` it never reaches the call to `print('Connected')` but instead just hangs at the `bus.connect(...)` call. The signal is seen on the bus as evident in the debug output:

> QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x7f3e60002b00) : connected successfully
>   QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x7f3e60002b00) got message (signal):
>   QDBusMessage(type=Signal, service="org.freedesktop.DBus",
>   path="/org/freedesktop/DBus", interface="org.freedesktop.DBus",
>   member="NameAcquired", signature="s", contents=(":1.137") )
>   QDBusConnectionPrivate(0x7f3e60002b00) delivery is suspended

Here is my minimal working example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtDBus import QDBusConnection, QDBusMessage


class DbusTest(QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        super(DbusTest, self).__init__()
        bus = QDBusConnection.systemBus()
        bus.connect(
            'org.freedesktop.DBus',
            '/org/freedesktop/DBus',
            'org.freedesktop.DBus',
            'NameAcquired',
            self.testMessage
        )
        print('Connected')

    @pyqtSlot(QDBusMessage)
    def testMessage(self, msg):
        print(msg)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    discoverer = DbusTest()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

What am I doing wrong? There must be something I overlooked so that the call to `bus.connect(...)` actually returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix your example like this:

```
    bus = QDBusConnection.systemBus()
    bus.registerObject('/', self)
    bus.connect( ...
```

However, I have to admit I don't exactly understand why it works (which is to say, I couldn't find any corroborating documentation). It does seem to make sense that you'd need to register the receiver object before attempting to make the connection, though.