# Connect to DBus signal - Correct syntax - PySide6

Tags: python, pyside, dbus, pyside6

can you help me with the correct syntax to connect to a DBus signal?

This is one of my many tries which at least runs and matches the [signature in the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtDBus/QDBusConnection.html#PySide6.QtDBus.PySide6.QtDBus.QDBusConnection.connect):

```
from PySide6 import QtDBus
from PySide6.QtCore import Q
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    __slots__ = ["__mainwidget"]
    __mainwidget:QWidget

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        service = 'org.freedesktop.DBus'
        path = '/org/freedesktop/DBus'
        iface = 'org.freedesktop.DBus'
        conn = QtDBus.QDBusConnection.systemBus()
        conn.connect(service, path, iface, "NameOwnerChanged", self, "nochangeslot")
        #smp = QtDBus.QDBusInterface(service, path, iface, connection=QtDBus.QDBusConnection.systemBus()


    def nochangeslot(self, arg:object) -> None:
        print(arg)
        pass
```

But it doesn't work and looks weird with the slot as string...

On the output I see:

```
qt.dbus.integration: Could not connect "org.freedesktop.DBus" to ochangeslot
```

Please consider this is a PySide6 issue and not a PyQt5 issue, the signature of the call is slightly different and my code doesn't hang like in similar topics on stackoverflow.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: I was in exchange with the Qt support and have now a solution. How to use the singals in newer version of PySide is really poor documented and would like to leave the code here for anyone who has the same problems. I still don't see why this was closed. After the code works, the issue from the linked topic comes into place, there I would place  the link for reference....

Comment: I previously closed the question as a duplicate because I hadn't realised that PySide was still using the old-style signal and slot syntax in its dbus APIs. This syntax was superseded long ago (during the lifetime of Qt4), and was well-documented by PyQt at the time - see [old-style](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html) *vs* [new-style](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html). Anyway, I have now added an answer that deals with this aspect of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This es the full solution to my initial post, I got this running with the QT/PySide support and they also acknowledged the hangig bug and a Python crash:

```
import sys
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PySide6 import QtDBus, QtCore
from PySide6.QtCore import QLibraryInfo, qVersion, Slot
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        service = "org.freedesktop.DBus"
        path = "/org/freedesktop/DBus"
        iface = "org.freedesktop.DBus"
        conn = QtDBus.QDBusConnection.systemBus()

        #without this, the conn.connect call hangs, seems to be a bug, is already reported and fixed.
        conn.registerObject('/', self)

        conn.connect(service, path, iface, "NameOwnerChanged", self, QtCore.SLOT("nameownerchanged(QString, QString, QString)"))    
        pass

    @Slot(str, str, str)
    def nameownerchanged(self, arg1:str, arg2:str, arg3:str) -> None:
        print(arg1)
        print(arg2)
        print(arg3)
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('Python {}.{}.{} {}'.format(sys.version_info[0], sys.version_info[1],
                                       sys.version_info[2], sys.platform))
    print(QLibraryInfo.build())
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(qVersion())
    window.resize(800, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with the example, the first of which is already answered here:

- [PyQt 5.6: connecting to a DBus signal hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38142809/984421)

So you firstly just need to add the following line to the example:

```
conn.registerObject('/', self)
```

The second problem is very easily fixed in PyQt (which is shown clearly in the question linked above). However, it seems PySide is still using the ugly and error-prone C++ syntax in it's dbus APIs, which can make connecting signals and slots extremely unintuitive if you're not a long-term user of PyQt/PySide. By contrast, PyQt sends a generic [QDBusMessage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdbusmessage.html), which greatly simplifies matters because there's no need to know the exact form of the signature beforehand. To illustrate the difference, here's two basic working examples:

**PyQt6**:

```
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtDBus

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__()
        service = 'org.freedesktop.DBus'
        path = '/org/freedesktop/DBus'
        iface = 'org.freedesktop.DBus'
        conn = QtDBus.QDBusConnection.systemBus()
        conn.registerObject('/', self)
        conn.connect(service, path, iface, 'NameAcquired', self.nochangeslot)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtDBus.QDBusMessage)
    def nochangeslot(self, msg):
        print(f'signature: {msg.signature()!r}, '
              f'arguments: {msg.arguments()!r}')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

**PySide6**:

```
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtDBus

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__()
        service = 'org.freedesktop.DBus'
        path = '/org/freedesktop/DBus'
        iface = 'org.freedesktop.DBus'
        conn = QtDBus.QDBusConnection.systemBus()
        conn.registerObject('/', self)
        conn.connect(service, path, iface, 'NameAcquired',
                     self, QtCore.SLOT('nochangeslot(QString)'))

    @QtCore.Slot(str)
    def nochangeslot(self, args):
        print(f'arguments: {args!r}')

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(['Test'])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Yes you are right, the question was closed in the meanwhile as a duplicate of the question you also linked. I solved it in the same way you did in exchange with the Qt PySide support, it is very unsatisfying in PySide. They also fixed this hanging bug and another bug in the DBus implementation, which totally crashed the Python interpreter. I switch from PyQt to PySide for a reason I don't remember anymore, I have to look.

Comment: Thank you for the hint with PyQt, I migrated my project back to PyQt and got all the DBus communication I need set up in hour. With PySide I wasted several days on this topic and still have the PropertiesChanged signal not running... I migrated from PyQt6 to PySide6, because no PyQt6 arm/Raspberry wheel exists on pypi and you have to compile it by yourself, which takes its time on a Raspberry... Or you take the system wide apt package python3-pyqt6,  but this is not available on Ubuntu 22.04...